# Access to files on CIFS partition from my application

Tags: android, samba, cifs

I've just mounted samba share to my Nexus 7 (CM 11) under root using kernel module.

Everything seems ok for applications (ES File Manager, Total Commander etc), I see files and can read them, even "cat" command from shell works. 
But I'm unable to read them from my app! Neither with native calls (open sets errno to ENOENT) nor FileInputStream.

I tried many names:

```
/storage/emulated/0/mounted_folder/file.txt
/storage/emulated/legacy/mounted_folder/file.txt
/sdcard/mounted_folder/file.txt
/mnt/shell/emulated/0/mounted_folder/file.txt
```

with root privelegies, with read-write permissions and many other variations, still no luck :(

What am I missing?

Comment: It's just call to fopen ("adb shell cat" commands works fine with the same path)

Comment: You will need to determine the path at which you have mounted the share from the mounting command utilized, by running the `mount` command from the shell without arguments, or by reading `/proc/mounts` as a text file and examining it.  Also beware that Android now supports per-process mounts, so it is possible (though perhaps not likely) that you could mount the share in such a way that it was only mounted for ADB, and not for apps.  Also your comment that you have tried this "with root privileges" is likely mistaken as even on rooted device, apps themselves do not run as root.

Comment: I've already found real path, it's "/mnt/shell/emulated/0/mounted_folder/file.txt" which I tried to open too. Folder was mounted for adb and apps, I've opened it from adb shell and android file managers. Apps can request root priveleges calling "su" in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem was in multi-user storage implementation. You can read the discussion and get patches here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2106480